# Array of functions?

Tags: scala

How can I create an array of functions in Scala so I can loop over them and call them to perform calculations?

```
def f1(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y

def f2(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x - y

def f3(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * y

def test() {
   val someValues1 = List(1, 2)
   val someValues2 = List(3, 4)
   val fnList = Array(f1,f2,f3)

   for (f <- fnList; a <- someValues1; b <- someValues2) {
     val result = f(a, b)
     println("Result=" + result)
   }
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your implementation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your question, you say that you want an array of functions. But there isn't a single function in your entire code snippet!

I'm guessing by the names `f1`, `f2` and `f3` that you thought those were functions. But they aren't: the `def` keyword is used to declare *methods*, not *functions*. Those two are *fundamentally different*!

So, if you want to use an array of functions, just make `f1`, `f2` and `f3` actually *be* functions instead of methods:

```
val f1: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
val f2: (Int, Int) => Int = _ - _
val f3: (Int, Int) => Int = _ * _
```

An alternative to that would be to actually *read* the error message, which tells you *exactly* what the problem is and how to fix it:

```
error: missing arguments for method f1 in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          val fnList = Array(f1,f2,f3)
                             ^
```

So, if you simply do what the error message tells you to do, namely convert the methods to functions using the `_` operator, everything will work fine:

```
val fnList = Array(f1 _, f2 _, f3 _)
```

The reason why you are getting the error message is simply because Scala allows you to leave off the parentheses in a method call. So, `f1` just means "call `f1` without an argument list", which is an error, because `f1` takes two arguments.

In some cases, when it is *really* painfully blatantly obvious that the argument cannot *possibly* be anything *but* a function, Scala will perform the conversion from method to function for you automatically. So, a third option would be to *make* it painfully blatantly obvious to Scala that you *do* have an array of functions, by, you know, declaring it as an array of functions:

```
val fnList: Array[(Int, Int) => Int] = Array(f1, f2, f3) // or
val fnList = Array[(Int, Int) => Int](f1, f2, f3)
```

Now that Scala *knows* that `fnList` is an array of functions, it no longer tries to call `f1`, instead it converts it to a function.

Answer (score 7):

Or write as:

```
scala> val fnList = Array(f1 _,f2 _,f3 _)
fnList: Array[(Int, Int) => Int] = Array(<function2>, <function2>, <function2>)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just provide the Type parameter for your Array:

```
val fnList = Array[(Int,Int)=>Int](f1, f2, f3)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you're asking, but you might also want to know that

```
val fnList = Array[(Int,Int) => Int](_ + _, _ - _, _ * _)
```

works.